# Unexpected floating point issue in pandas.to_numeric

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, floating-point

What is the explanation for this seemingly inconsistent floating point behavior of [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)?

```
In [116]: pd.to_numeric([100.018], errors='ignore', downcast='float')
Out[116]: array([100.018], dtype=float32)

In [117]: pd.DataFrame([100.018]).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='float')
Out[117]:
            0
0  100.017998

In [118]: pd.DataFrame([100.018], dtype=np.float64).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore', downcast='float').dtypes
Out[118]:
0    float32
dtype: object
```

It seems to me that the `downcast` is not working correctly with the docs
as `100.018` can be casted to a `np.float32`

> If not `None`, and if the data has been successfully cast to a numerical
>   dtype (or if the data was numeric to begin with), **downcast that
>   resulting data to the smallest numerical dtype possible** according to
>   the following rules:
>
> - `'integer'` or `'signed'`: smallest signed `int` dtype (min.: `np.int8`)
> - `'unsigned'`: smallest unsigned `int` dtype (min.: `np.uint8`)
> - `'float'`: smallest `float` dtype (min.: `np.float32`)

```
In [119]: import pandas as pd

In [120]: pd.__version__
Out[120]: '0.23.4'
```

Comment: please refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken I think you are looking for this.

Comment: there is NO inconsistency - in both cases you'll get the same dtype.

Comment: i got "float32" for both cases... (Pandas 0.24.2)

Comment: Thanks for comments, I had thought previously that the `dtype` was different between both. It appears that the difference is just the length of the floating point as per @MohamedThasinah  which can be found by `print(np.finfo('float32'))`